# Run a C program in a server running lighttpd having mod-fastcgi enabled

Tags: lighttpd

I have a server running lighttpd 1.45 version running and I pplan on using fastCGI.

I would want to know how to execute a binary in the server?

(For eg. if I give type in the browser "http:serverip:port number/start" I would like my binary to start executing in the server and if I give "http:serverip:port number/stop" , I would like the execution to be terminated.)

If not in browser , how else can i give a command to my server to start and stop the execution? I have a basic FCGI server running which I set up from this site: 
"http://yaikhom.com/2014/12/18/handling-requests-c-fast-cgi-and-lighttpd.html"

(P.S. I am new to web development)

Comment: The binary is also residing in the server

Comment: Welcome to SO. As your question handles server configuration, you might better place it [here](https://serverfault.com/), or?